# Got multiple issues when running the tutorial project "table-walkthrough" on IDEA

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm currently trying to debug the tutorial project "table-walkthrough" on IDEA on a standalone Flink environment. I installed the required software (Java 8 or 11, Maven, Docker) according to the tutorial. I'll provide some key environment info about the running environment before describing the issues as follows:

```
1. OS: Fedora 34;
2. Java version: 1.8;
3. Maven version: 3.6.3;
4. Docker version: 20.10.7;
5. Flink version: 1.13.1;
6. Scala version: 2.11;
7. No Kafka, Yarn, etc. are installed.
```

The issues are:
When I run the code on IDEA, it returns me WARNs and exceptions. Due to this tutorial project did not require things to be installed like Kafka, Yarn, I couldn't find any proper solution(s) for my problem after searching on the web. The issue report of different WARN/exception types are listed below:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/302/lib/idea_rt.jar=39087:/var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-community/302/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_291-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/IdeaProjects/flink-playgrounds-master/table-walkthrough/target/classes:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-table-api-java/1.12.1/flink-table-api-java-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-table-common/1.12.1/flink-table-common-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-files/1.12.1/flink-connector-files-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-base/1.12.1/flink-connector-base-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-asm-7/7.1-12.0/flink-shaded-asm-7-7.1-12.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.15/slf4j-api-1.7.15.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/force-shading/1.12.1/force-shading-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11/1.12.1/flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-java/1.12.1/flink-java-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.5/commons-math3-3.5.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-java_2.11/1.12.1/flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-file-sink-common/1.12.1/flink-file-sink-common-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-guava/18.0-12.0/flink-shaded-guava-18.0-12.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.11/1.12.1/flink-streaming-scala_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-scala_2.11/1.12.1/flink-scala_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.12/scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.12/scala-library-2.11.12.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.12/scala-compiler-2.11.12.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.5/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.5.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-table-planner-blink_2.11/1.12.1/flink-table-planner-blink_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-table-api-scala_2.11/1.12.1/flink-table-api-scala_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-table-api-scala-bridge_2.11/1.12.1/flink-table-api-scala-bridge_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-table-runtime-blink_2.11/1.12.1/flink-table-runtime-blink_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/codehaus/janino/janino/3.0.11/janino-3.0.11.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/codehaus/janino/commons-compiler/3.0.11/commons-compiler-3.0.11.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/calcite/avatica/avatica-core/1.17.0/avatica-core-1.17.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.10/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/javassist/javassist/3.19.0-GA/javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-clients_2.11/1.12.1/flink-clients_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-core/1.12.1/flink-core-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-annotations/1.12.1/flink-annotations-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-metrics-core/1.12.1/flink-metrics-core-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.24.0/kryo-2.24.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-1.2.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-runtime_2.11/1.12.1/flink-runtime_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-queryable-state-client-java/1.12.1/flink-queryable-state-client-java-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-hadoop-fs/1.12.1/flink-hadoop-fs-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/commons-io/commons-io/2.7/commons-io-2.7.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-netty/4.1.49.Final-12.0/flink-shaded-netty-4.1.49.Final-12.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-jackson/2.10.1-12.0/flink-shaded-jackson-2.10.1-12.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-zookeeper-3/3.4.14-12.0/flink-shaded-zookeeper-3-3.4.14-12.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.5.21/akka-actor_2.11-2.5.21.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/typesafe/config/1.3.3/config-1.3.3.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-java8-compat_2.11/0.7.0/scala-java8-compat_2.11-0.7.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/typesafe/akka/akka-stream_2.11/2.5.21/akka-stream_2.11-2.5.21.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.2/reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.11/0.3.7/ssl-config-core_2.11-0.3.7.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/typesafe/akka/akka-protobuf_2.11/2.5.21/akka-protobuf_2.11-2.5.21.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/typesafe/akka/akka-slf4j_2.11/2.5.21/akka-slf4j_2.11-2.5.21.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/clapper/grizzled-slf4j_2.11/1.3.2/grizzled-slf4j_2.11-1.3.2.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/github/scopt/scopt_2.11/3.5.0/scopt_2.11-3.5.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.4/snappy-java-1.1.4.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/twitter/chill_2.11/0.7.6/chill_2.11-0.7.6.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/com/twitter/chill-java/0.7.6/chill-java-0.7.6.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/lz4/lz4-java/1.6.0/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-optimizer_2.11/1.12.1/flink-optimizer_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3.1/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.7/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-csv/1.12.1/flink-csv-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-jdbc_2.11/1.12.1/flink-connector-jdbc_2.11-1.12.1.jar:/home/AkatsukiG5/Documents/mavenRepo/org/apache/flink/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11/1.12.1/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.12.1.jar org.apache.flink.playgrounds.spendreport.SpendReport
09:44:59,723 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - Log file environment variable 'log.file' is not set.
09:44:59,724 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.WebMonitorUtils           - JobManager log files are unavailable in the web dashboard. Log file location not found in environment variable 'log.file' or configuration key 'web.log.path'.
09:45:00,108 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Source: TableSourceScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, transactions, watermark=[-($2, 5000:INTERVAL SECOND)]]], fields=[account_id, amount, transaction_time]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,109 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Source: TableSourceScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, transactions, watermark=[-($2, 5000:INTERVAL SECOND)]]], fields=[account_id, amount, transaction_time]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,108 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,110 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,109 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,113 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,117 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,126 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,131 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,135 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,147 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name GroupWindowAggregate(groupBy=[account_id], window=[TumblingGroupWindow('log_ts, transaction_time, 3600000)], properties=[EXPR$0], select=[account_id, SUM(amount) AS EXPR$1, start('log_ts) AS EXPR$0]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,148 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name GroupWindowAggregate(groupBy=[account_id], window=[TumblingGroupWindow('log_ts, transaction_time, 3600000)], properties=[EXPR$0], select=[account_id, SUM(amount) AS EXPR$1, start('log_ts) AS EXPR$0]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,149 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name GroupWindowAggregate(groupBy=[account_id], window=[TumblingGroupWindow('log_ts, transaction_time, 3600000)], properties=[EXPR$0], select=[account_id, SUM(amount) AS EXPR$1, start('log_ts) AS EXPR$0]) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
09:45:00,183 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - GroupWindowAggregate(groupBy=[account_id], window=[TumblingGroupWindow('log_ts, transaction_time, 3600000)], properties=[EXPR$0], select=[account_id, SUM(amount) AS EXPR$1, start('log_ts) AS EXPR$0]) -> Calc(select=[account_id, EXPR$0 AS log_ts, EXPR$1 AS amount]) -> Sink: Sink(table=[default_catalog.default_database.spend_report], fields=[account_id, log_ts, amount]) (7/8)#0 (fe35e811ba35b8be33b2188d9293ae07) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.io.IOException: unable to open JDBC writer
at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.open(AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.java:58)
at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.JdbcBatchingOutputFormat.open(JdbcBatchingOutputFormat.java:116)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.OutputFormatSinkFunction.open(OutputFormatSinkFunction.java:65)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.sink.SinkOperator.open(SinkOperator.java:63)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:426)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$2(StreamTask.java:535)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:525)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:565)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:755)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:570)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.connection.SimpleJdbcConnectionProvider.getConnection(SimpleJdbcConnectionProvider.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.establishConnection(AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.java:63)
at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.open(AbstractJdbcOutputFormat.java:56)
... 13 more
09:45:03,959 WARN  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils  - Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka
09:45:03,958 WARN  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils  - Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka
09:45:03,963 WARN  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser  - Error while loading kafka-version.properties: null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, it returned the WARNs and exceptions like "log.file" environment not set,  JobManager log files are unavailable in the web dashboard, jdbc driver exception, couldn't resolve server kafka:9092, etc.
I have successfully run the tutorial project "FraudDetector" before by just following the tutorial itself. However, I have done so much work for this one and it still not working :(
If anyone could help me figured out those issues, I'll appreciate it!

Best regards,

Comment: There is an `IOException: unable to open JDBC writer` which I suppose that you need to start a MySql docker image

Comment: Hi Felipe, did you mean that I shall start the docker first, then the project?

Comment: I don't know. Probably yes. I only saw this error on your stacktrace and it seems that the project is trying to connect to MySql. I tried to search the link for this tutorial but I didn't find. Could you post the link so I can also take a look?

Comment: It's a project contained in the github repository named flink-playgrounds. The github link is: https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds. And the official tutorial link is: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/try-flink/table_api/